# How do I use a StoryBoard to animate a SolidColorBrush in a UserControl

Tags: wpf

I'm getting very confused by WPF. I need to make some changes to some code in a UI for a webservice. The UI consists of cells which derive from UserControl. Each cell should change colour for a number of seconds every time the data changes, this might be a value increasing, going down, being initialised etc. After a set number of seconds the cell should be painted white again. The update is performed by calling a member function for the cell, which takes an enum type and the new value as parameters. The enum type tells the function what sort of update has occurred, and so the StoryBoard object in the cell should know which colour to paint the cell based on the the value of the enum parameter. I understand how to event trigger a storyboard, but I can't make too many changes. Is there anyway I can make a StoryBoard do something each time a function is called, and tell it what to do based on an enum?

I'm doing some refactoring of someone else's code to replace a very expensive mechanism for doing the update - does this sound like I should make more significant design changes rather than just rewriting what's going on inside the member function? Is there anyway of animating the cell while salvaging the design?

Comment: It's hard to truly understand what you're wanting to do here, but it sounds like you want a custom control?

Comment: Yeah: I have  

class CustomControl : UserControl
{
public CustomControl(){InitializeComponent();}
public void DoUpdate(UpdateCode code, String updateValue){ //do stuff to the colour of this according to the UpdateCode
}

Comment: Do you have a custom control or a user control that you're working with. It makes a very big difference.